# Add labels (i.e., "A", "B") to facet wrap ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Figure with desired locations of "A" and "B"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPUiB.png)

I would like to place the "A" and "B" labels as shown in upper left above above the tick axis labels. I would also like to remove the grid background plotted in the "NA" area in the lower left. Code to arrange the two plots:

```
    twoplots <- grid.arrange(Aplot, Bplot, heights=c(8,2),nrow = 2,
         layout_matrix=rbind(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),c(NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)))
```

Comment: If you haven't seen it before, package **cowplot** makes arranging plots in a grid and doing things like adding labels pretty easy.  You can see the vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html)

Comment: That worked! Thanks.

Comment: If you found a solution you should as it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(cowplot)
twoplots <- plot_grid(Aplot,Bplot,labels="AUTO",ncol=1,align='v',axis='r',label_x=0,hjust=0,label_size=10,rel_heights = c(5,1))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.